# Do norton ghost has a feature similar to acronis one click restore?

Tags: disk-cloning

Clonzilla and Acronis has this recovery program and pc image in one disk feature, does Norton have this feature too? if yes what is it call? i cant seem to find it

acronis true image one click restore - allows me to create my own Recovery disc of my pc, a disc that is bootable and allows me to restore my hdd in bios level without the need to have a program disc and additional disc which contains my backup image.

Comment: yes, i mean norton ghost does it have similar feature like acronis one click restore

Comment: I know Ghost Solution Suite (GSS) has WinPE support to create bootable discs but you'll have to look up the details.

Comment: You can make a recovery partition that will load freedos, then run ghost from there to restore a ghost image from the recovery partition., [tutorial here which give the basics.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yDbsh32XmQ)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but here is the way to restore an image using Ghost:

If your backup file is on CD or DVD, you need to get your disc set and make certain you have all of them. And because you've labeled them so well and know exactly where to find them, you can retrieve them quickly and identify the data you need.
Restoring a drive

Here you are at that magic moment when you get to put your hard work, the backup, back online by restoring the drive from which the backup was created.

To restore a drive, follow these steps:

1. Open Norton Ghost.
2. From Basic view, click Restore a Drive or, from Advanced view, choose Tools --> Restore Drive.
3. Select the backup image you're restoring from, and click Next.

If it's on a disc, insert the first disc from the backup set into your CD or DVD drive).

4. In the Restore Destination window, choose the drive where you want to restore the backup, and click Next.
5. Select the options you want to apply:

• Verify image file before restore: Assures that the restore doesn't fail in the middle.

• Check for file system errors: Ensures data integrity when data is written to the drive being restored.

• Resize drive to fill unallocated space: Lets Ghost adjust the drive size as needed to match the data being restored.

• Set drive active: Select this when the drive being restored is going to hold a bootable operating system. Normally, however, if you're restoring a bootable hard disk from your Ghost backup, this is handled for you automatically so you don't need to specify this.

• Partition type: Choose either primary or logical. Normally, you do not need to select this since Ghost knows what it's backed up.

• Drive letter: Select the drop-down list box to specify the drive letter for the drive being restored.

6. Click Next and review your choices.
7. Click Next again to begin the actual restoration process.

Comment: so its not possible for norton ghost to create my own Recovery disc of my pc? a disc that is bootable and allows me to restore my hdd in bios level without the need to have a program disc and additional disc which contains my backup image.

Comment: nope, you still need to boot ghost before restoring